# WooCommerce Deposits: enabele deposit for certain product IDs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to disable certain product ID's of using the plugin WooComerce Deposit.

The filter is `wc_deposits_product_enable_deposit`: it controls whether deposit is enabled disabled for a product. variables passed through this filter are `$enabled` ( boolean) and `$product_id`.

I have tried the code

```php
add_filter('wc_deposits_product_enable_deposit','wcdp_custom_wc_deposits_disable_productid',10,3);
function wcdp_custom_wc_deposits_disable_productid($enabled , $product_id) {
    
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        
    if ($product = 6283) {
        $enabled = false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
```

Unfortunately without the desired result. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains some mistakes

- `wc_deposits_product_enable_deposit`: controls whether deposit is enabled disabled for a product. variables passed through this filter are `$enabled` ( boolean) and `$product_id`
- You compare `$product` with an id, while this should be the `$product_id`
- The use of `wc_get_product( $product_id )` is therefore not necessary
- To apply this for multiple product IDs you can use i[n_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php),
  which allows you to check multiple productIDs at once

So you get:

```php
function filter_wc_deposits_product_enable_deposit( $enabled, $product_id ) {
    // Products IDs, several can be added, separated by a comma
    $product_ids = array( 6283, 30 );
    
    // Checks if a value exists in an array
    if ( in_array( $product_id, $product_ids ) ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }
    
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'wc_deposits_product_enable_deposit', 'filter_wc_deposits_product_enable_deposit', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks this helps but unfortunately does not work for me for some reasons. The deposit plugin functionality is still there at the checkout page.

Comment: @Franceoutdoors 
as you stated in your question _"it controls whether deposit is enabled disabled for a product"_ - in other words, if you want to apply this to the checkout page you will have to use a different hook. However, this was not mentioned in your question

Comment: Ok I understand . I though this hook would work at the checkout page of a given product which is what I am looking for. Any idea then ?

Comment: @7uc1f3r what would it be like for checkout page? I am having the same problem